# Backbone collection url not defined

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have the following Backbone code, that's supposed to create a collection with a model, and create a new model instance within it, and save it on the server.

```
var Project = Backbone.Model.extend({});

var Projects = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Project,
    url: "/api/projects"
});

var projects = new Projects();

projects.add({
    "title": "My Project"
}).sync();
```

However, I get the following error when running this;

```
A "url" property or function must be specified
```

I thought the model would inherit the `url` property from the collection [as per the documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-url). Why isn't it? What's wrong?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6L8v4dj8/

Answer (score 1):

according to what I see in documentation you should call

`projects.sync('create', projects.models[0])` http://backbonejs.org/#Sync

Comment: `create` will work for me in this case, but I don't understand why. I also have the same problem when trying to sync a `remove`, and afaik there is no similar op+sync method for that, is there?

Answer (score 1):

In this case you could use method `create`, for example:

```
var Project = Backbone.Model.extend({});

var Projects = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Project,
    url: "/api/projects"
});

var projects = new Projects();

projects.create({
    title: "My Project"
});
```

> [Creating a model will cause an immediate "add" event to be triggered on the collection, a "request" event as the new model is sent to the server, as well as a "sync" event, once the server has responded with the successful creation of the model.](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-create)

[documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-create)

Comment: Please see my comment in the above answer; how do I use `sync` properly with commands like `remove`?